# How to override only gradient content of a webpage using external css?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page which consists of an inline CSS as shown below:

```
<td data-sort="31929.59" class="text-right" style="background-image:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.01), rgba(0,0,0,0.001) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 100%
```

```js
//Can't modify JS
```

```css
.shoot
{
background-image:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,255,0,0.01), rgba(0,255,0,0.001) 0%, rgba(0,255,0,0.2) 0%, rgba(0,255,0,0.2) 88%, rgba(0,255,0,0.01) 88%, rgba(0,255,0,0.001) 100%) !important;
}
/*Here I changed the colour type but I just want gradient to change and not it's length*/
```

```html
<!--Can't Modify HTML-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sample</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Quantity 1</th>
      <th>Quantity 2</th>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Snap</td>
          <td class = "shoot" style="background-image:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.01), rgba(0,0,0,0.001) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 40%, rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 40%, rgba(0,0,0,0.001) 40%)">1.24</td>
          <td>1.46</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Shoot</td>
          <td class = "shoot" style="background-image:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.01), rgba(0,0,0,0.001) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.001) 50%)">1.34</td>
          <td>1.36</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sharp</td>
          <td class="shoot"style="background-image:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.01), rgba(0,0,0,0.001) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 20%, rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 20%, rgba(0,0,0,0.001) 20%)">1.14</td>
          <td>1.36</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Snake</td>
          <td class="shoot" style="background-image:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.01), rgba(0,0,0,0.001) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,0.001) 25%)">1.22</td>
          <td>1.16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sleep</td>
          <td class="shoot" style="background-image:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.01), rgba(0,0,0,0.001) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 12%, rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 12%, rgba(0,0,0,0.001) 12%)">1.14</td>
          <td>1.43</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Smoke</td>
          <td class="shoot" style="background-image:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.01), rgba(0,0,0,0.001) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 40%, rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 40%, rgba(0,0,0,0.001) 40%)">1.24</td>
          <td>1.16</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

, rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 100%, rgba(0,0,0,0.001) 100%)" title="31929.59">31.9k

which looks somewhat like this:

[image]

What I wanted is to make these gradients colours turn green without altering their % values that is:

rgba(**0,0,0,0.001**) *0%*

I want to alter the bold part but keep italicised part as it is. Now the problem is that I could only alter external css of this website and not the internal inline CSS. From this post, I got to know a way about how to override internal CSS by doing this:

```
{
background-image:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,255,0,0.01), rgba(0,255,0,0.001) 0%, rgba(0,255,0,0.2) 0%, rgba(0,255,0,0.2) 88%, rgba(0,255,0,0.01) 88%, rgba(0,255,0,0.001) 100%) !important;
}
```

Output:

[image]

by using **!important** tag. but the problem is that if I use this, I have to override the gradient values too (rgba(**0,0,0,0.001**) *0%* : the italicized part). I just want to alter gradient schematic part, i.e. the part inside rgba().

Please let me know if there' any way to pick gradient schema (inside rgba part from my external CSS) and the gradient length % (from inline css: which I don't have access too).

Comment: Can you post a snippet example of your code?

Comment: Can you use JS or not?

Comment: Yeah I have posted a snippet of inline CSS at the top and my external CSS code here, do you want HTML too?

Comment: @UnbrandedManchester no I have access to only external CSS HTML and JS is fixed.

Comment: I don't think its going to be possible without JS I'm afraid.

Comment: A snippet is code that can be executed to reproduce your question, and not a single line of code.

Comment: @Islam Elshobokshy thanks for the suggestion added the snippet as well. Please note that I could only alter external css and nothing else.